# Performance issue on conditional join in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Right now, I am selecting data with this query (simplyfied):

```
SELECT person.*, pty.*
FROM PERSON person
     LEFT JOIN PARTNER partner 
     ON partner.FK_BPE_ISTC_ID = person.BSPE_ISTC_ID
     INNER JOIN PTY pty 
     ON pty.PTY_ISTC_ID = IIF(person.FORGN_ISTC_IND != 0, person.FORGN_ISTC_IND, partner.FRGN_ISTC_ID)
```

The Problem is that it takes so much time to complete and the execution plan looks like this:

[image: Execution plan]

Almost 20 million rows (picture) need to be processed to get me 25 thousand rows in the end.

Is there a better approach to join the PTY table with the condition?

Comment: Questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IIF` function used in the `ON` condition will make the query non sargable

Below query will perform better when there is a index on any of these columns `person.FORGN_ISTC_IND`, `person.FORGN_ISTC_IND`, `partner.FRGN_ISTC_ID`

```
SELECT person.*,
       pty.*
FROM   PERSON person
       LEFT JOIN PARTNER partner
              ON partner.FK_BPE_ISTC_ID = person.BSPE_ISTC_ID
       INNER JOIN PTY pty
               ON ( person.FORGN_ISTC_IND != 0
                    AND pty.PTY_ISTC_ID = person.FORGN_ISTC_IND )
                   OR pty.PTY_ISTC_ID = partner.FRGN_ISTC_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

Do multiple left joins:

```
SELECT person.*, 
       COALESCE(ptyp.col1, ptypa.col1) as col1,
       . . .
FROM PERSON p LEFT JOIN PARTNER
     partner pa
     ON pa.FK_BPE_ISTC_ID = p.BSPE_ISTC_ID LEFT JOIN
     pty ptyp
     ON p.FORGN_ISTC_IND <> 0 AND ptyp.PTY_ISTC_ID = p.FORGN_ISTC_IND LEFT JOIN
     pty ptypa
     ON pty.PTY_ISTC_ID = 0 AND ptypa.PTY_ISTC_ID = pa.FRGN_ISTC_ID;
```

SQL Server can do a much better job optimizing simple `join` conditions.  You need to choose the appropriate value in the `select`.